# Swiper.js vertical slides not working using ngx-swiper-wrapper

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, swiper.js

I have two stackblitz examples, the first with horizontal slides and then I change them to vertical slides.
When I make this change, the height gets blown up to something very large.

Any help understanding this?

Here is the stackblitz link that works with horizontal slides [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2vfx7d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) - working

Here is the stackblitz link with vertical slides [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-emz7sk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) - css alignment is off

The only difference is I've changed

> direction: 'horizontal',

to

> direction: 'vertical',

in the config here

```js
config: SwiperConfigInterface = {
    observer: true,
    observeParents: true,
    observeSlideChildren: true,
    direction: 'vertical',
    threshold: 50,
    spaceBetween: 0,
    slidesPerView: 1,
    centeredSlides: true,
    slideToClickedSlide: true,
    pagination: this.pagination,
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your wrapper has height `auto` and swiper library calculates height by itself.

Specify boundaries for your wrapper and it should be enough:

```
.card-body {
  height: 200px;
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vefa9z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)**