# Swiper React vertical extends across all page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

I'm using Next with swiper to create a vertical carousel, but does not seems to work correctly when using this property, making the `Swiper` component to get an insane height that appears to be infinite

[image]

I've looking for solutions in posts like [Swiper.js vertical slides not working using ngx-swiper-wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163425/swiper-js-vertical-slides-not-working-using-ngx-swiper-wrapper) (also, that post is about Angular, can't be duplicate) but seems to not fitting my problem, do someone knows what's wrong?

Here's a minimal example:

```
'use client';

import React from 'react'

import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import 'swiper/css';

function TestPage() 
{
    const dummyArrary = [...Array(3).keys()];
    const colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];

    return (
        <div>
            <Swiper direction='vertical'>
                
                { dummyArrary.map((elem, index) =>
                    <SwiperSlide key={'slide'+index}>

                        <div style={{width: '100%', height: '400px', backgroundColor: colors[index]}}>
                            Slide {index+1}
                        </div>

                    </SwiperSlide>
                )}

            </Swiper>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TestPage
```

**EDIT:** Note that I would prefer to just fit the contents inside carousel instead of placing a fixed size if possible